# QTextedit set anchor and scroll to it

Tags: c++, qt, anchor, qtextedit

How can I set an anchor in `QTextEdit`?

There seems to be a method to scroll to an anchor, but not any method to set actually one.

So I tried this, but it does not work.

```
mTextEdit->setHtml("some html stuff");
mTextEdit->append("<a href=\"#word\">word</a>");
mTextEdit->scrollToAnchor("word");
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to give the **name** attribute to your anchor , like this:

```
mTextEdit->append("<a name=\"scrollToMe\" href=\"#word\">word</a>");
```

and then call the scrollToAnchor function:

```
mTextEdit->scrollToAnchor("scrollToMe");
```