# QTextBrowser scrollToAnchor call not scrolling properly

Tags: python, anchor, pyside2, qtextbrowser

I'm having trouble getting [QTextBrowser.scrollToAnchor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#scrollToAnchor) to scroll properly. The `on_anchorClicked` signal is firing, but I'm having difficulties determining what's going wrong after that.

I've double checked that my markdown file anchors are correctly labelled by previewing in [ReText](https://github.com/retext-project/retext/tree/7ccdb5c0d342714528bcb2709a51e229105643ad/ReText) (the anchors work as long as I keep the WebKit preview box unchecked). (I'm also aware of the HTML naming requirement [as mentioned in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20678610/qtextedit-set-anchor-and-scroll-to-it)).

The main difference I see between my implementation and what they're doing is that I'm using `QTextBrowser.setMarkdown` to populate my markdown preview widget. Does anyone know if this messes with the way that QTextBrowser sets the anchors?

Sample code follows:

```
import PySide2 as ps2

class App(ps2.QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parents=None):
        self.ui.textBrowser.anchorClicked.connect(self.on_anchorClicked)

    def read_file(self, file_path):
        file_handle = ps2.QtCore.QFile(file_path.absoluteFilePath())
        if not file_handle.open(ps2.QtCore.QFile.ReadOnly | ps2.QtCore.QFile.Text):
            return False

        stream = ps2.QtCore.QTextStream(file_handle)
        self.ui.textBrowser.setMarkdown(stream.readAll())
    
    def on_anchorClicked(self, link):
        url = link.url()
        if url.startswith("#"):
            print("Attempting to scroll to anchor {}".format(url[1:]))
            self.ui.textBrowser.scrollToAnchor(url[1:])
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]